# How to compute the outer sum (similar to outer product

Tags: pytorch, numpy-einsum

Given tensors `x` and `y`, each with shape `(num_batches, d)`, how can I use PyTorch to compute the sum of every combination of `x` and `y` within a batch?

This is similar to outer product, except we don't want to multiply, but **sum**.  (This implies that I could solve this by exponentiating, outer product, and taking the log, but of course that has numerical and performance disadvantages).

It could be done via cartesian product and then summing each of the combinations.

Essentially, I'd like `osum[b, i, j] == x[b, i] + y[b, j]`.  Can PyTorch do this in tensors, without loops?

Comment: Related to [tag:numpy-einsum], you would be able to use einsum if the operation was of the form `osum[b, i, j] = x[b, i] * y[b, j]`... Ein-summation accumulates (*i.e.* sums) element wise products, not sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done, by introducing singleton dimensions into `x` and `y` and [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) along these singleton dimensions:

```py
osum = x[..., None] + y[:, None, :]
```

For example:

```py
x = torch.arange(6).view(2,3)
y = x * 10
osum = x[..., None] + y[:, None, :]
```

Results with:

> ```
> tensor([[[ 0, 10, 20],
>          [ 1, 11, 21],
>          [ 2, 12, 22]],
>
>         [[33, 43, 53],
>          [34, 44, 54],
>          [35, 45, 55]]])
> ```

---

**Update (July, 14th):** How it works?

You have two tensors, `x` and `y` of shape `b`x`n`, and you want to compute:

```py
osum[b,i,j] = x[b, i] + y[b, j]
```

We can, conceptually, create new variables `xx` and `yy` by repeating each element of `x` and `y` along a third dimension, such that:

```py
xx[b, i, j] == x[b, i]  # for all j
yy[b, i, j] == y[b, j]  # for all i
```

With these new variables, it is easy to see that:

```py
osum = xx + yy
```

since, by deinition

```
osum[b, i, j] == xx[b, i, j] + yy[b, i, j] == x[b, i] + y[b, j]
```

Now, you can use commands such as [`torch.expand`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.expand.html#torch.Tensor.expand) or [`torch.repeat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.repeat.html)  to *explicitly* create `xx` and `yy` - but why bother? since their elements are just trivial repetitions of the elements along specific dimensions, [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) does this *implicitly* for you.

Comment: Thanks. I find this type of broadcasting opaque.  1. Can you explain how it works? 2. Is there a way to do something similar, so that it's explicit? Or, at the least, can I do the broadcast explicitly, so that the code makes it clear exactly what it happening?

Comment: @SRobertJames please see my update

Answer (score 1):

You can perform such operation using broadcasting:

```
>>> x = torch.randint(0,10,(2,4))
tensor([[0, 6, 5, 8],
        [3, 0, 7, 5]])
>>> y = torch.randint(0,10,(2,5))
tensor([[6, 9, 9, 8, 7],
        [0, 4, 6, 2, 5]])

>>> x[:,:,None].shape
(2, 4, 1)

>>> y[:,None].shape
(2, 1, 5])
```

Adding a singleton to dimensions which differ ensures the 'outer' operation
is performed.

```
>>> osum = x[:,:,None] + y[:,None]
tensor([[[ 6,  9,  9,  8,  7],
         [12, 15, 15, 14, 13],
         [11, 14, 14, 13, 12],
         [14, 17, 17, 16, 15]],

        [[ 3,  7,  9,  5,  8],
         [ 0,  4,  6,  2,  5],
         [ 7, 11, 13,  9, 12],
         [ 5,  9, 11,  7, 10]]])
```